# How do I pull values from inputs in a list using something like this.val()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list which has input fields per list item. The coding is below:

```
<ol>
<span id="bandListForShow">
    <li>The Heavy Hustle <label for="new-band"> - Amount: </label> <input type="number" class="bandSettleAmount" id="0"></li>
    <li>The Breaker Boys<label for="new-band"> - Amount: </label> <input type="number" class="bandSettleAmount"
            id="2"></li>
</span>
```

This list can grow or shrink depending on how many bands may be needed, each band would have this input field with an ID pulled from a master DB elsewhere, which is then assigned to the input ID. The ID numbers correspond with the index in the DB, hence why it skips from 0 to 2, it doesn't have to be sequential, just needs to match the particular band that's on the list.

I'm trying to collect the numerical value in that list using the following function, but apparently you can't use this.val().... any suggestions?

```
    $("input.bandSettleAmount").each(function () {
  settledShowList[totalNumberOfShows].BandSplit.push(this.val());
});
```

Comment: `this` refers to the actual element. If you want to use the jQuery method, you have to wrap it in a jQuery collection first. (or, avoid jQuery entirely and just use `.value`)

Comment: Have you tried using $(this).val()?

Comment: @Snake14 no I haven't, I'm pretty new to coding so I haven't learned all the syntax yet, I'll try that now.

Comment: @CertainPerformance can I use .value within jquery? I'll try it but figured I'd ask too!

Comment: `.val()` is the jQuery equivalent of the native `.value`.

Comment: @Snake14 your suggestion worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).val();` to get value inside `each` loop. if you need get the id of input element use `$(this).attr('id')`.

Check the working Plunker : https://embed.plnkr.co/NH2ewv4NwKqD4AiIHydD/

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.